How to fire icecandidate event on setting local description?
I was learning webRTC and encountered this problem. I have created a peerConnection without using any media(audio or video).
I have created the offer and set the local description. As fas as I know icecandidate event is triggered as soon as the local description is set. Accordingly I have coded and used console.log(event.candidate). But not getting the desired output.Please go through the code below and correct me where I have gone wrong.
const configuration = { 
    iceServers: [{ 
        urls:['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302','stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'] 
    }] 
};
const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event)=>{
    if (event.candidate) {
        console.log('New ICE candidate:', event.candidate);
        // Display the ICE candidate for manual exchange
        // const iceCandidatesTextArea = document.getElementById('iceCandidates');
        // iceCandidatesTextArea.value += JSON.stringify(event.candidate) + '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("All ICE candidates gathered");
    }
};

// Add event listener for ICE candidates
async function createOffer() {
    try{
        const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        console.log(peerConnection);
    }catch(error){
        console.log("error generating offer",error);
    } 
}

createOffer();
I tried out all the possible ways to print the ice candidates but no output obtained!!

onicecandidate fires after setLocalDescription for any media lines. Since you have not added a MediaStreamTrack or created a data channel your SDP will not have any (i.e. your SDP does not contain any line starting with m=) and hence onicecandidate does not fire.
